# How to change class name of two IDs at same time using js?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two IDs in same name ! if any one clicked among them , i need to change the class name of the both IDs. i know we should use ID for single use. Because of my situation(I have two classes for button ) so i have moved to ID.
Her is my code if i click one id that name only changes another one is remains same

```
<button class="success" id="1" onClick="reply(this.id)"> Added </button>

<button class="success" id="1" onClick="reply(this.id)"> Added </button>
```

js function

```
function reply(clicked_id)
{
document.getElementById(clicked_id).setAttribute('class', 'failed');

var el = document.getElementById(clicked_id);

   if (el.firstChild.data == "Added") 
   {
       el.firstChild.data = "Add";
   }

}
```

if i use instead of 'class' to `id` while renaming class which one will be renamed `success` class or 'class name 1' ?

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same ID, it's invalid markup

Comment: Oh, i have if i use `class` instead of `id` there will problem will occur. so how to do this?

Comment: what problem will occur if you use class instead of id, you should not have same ids.

Comment: if i use two class which while changing class name which one will be changed?

Comment: i have updated my answer with a pure JS version, so best of both worlds now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pure JS Is Second Example**

My JS Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eunzs7rz/

This example will use the class attribute only to perform the switching that you need, its a extremely basic example as do not want to go beyond what is needed... Also i forgot to remove the id's in the JS Fiddle Example.. so just ignore them

THE CSS:

```
.success {
    background-color:#00f;
}
.failed {
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

THE HTML:

```
<button class="success"> Added </button>
<button class="success"> Added </button>
```

THE JAVSCRIPT:

```
$(function() {
    $(".success").click(function(){
        Reply(this);
    });

});
function Reply(oElm) {
    $(oElm).attr('class', 'failed');
}
```

**EDIT - PURE JAVASCRIPT VERSION**

Sorry, did not think to check the post tags if this was pure JS. But here you go anyway ;)

```
<style>
    .success {
        background-color:#00f;
    }
    .failed {
        background-color:#f00;
    }
</style>
<button class="success" onclick="Reply(this)"> Added </button>
<button class="success" onclick="Reply(this)"> Added </button>
<script>
    function Reply(oElm) {
        oElm.className  = 'failed';
    }
</script>
```

**THE MAIN THING HERE**

Once you have the element either by using 'this' or by using 'getElementBy', you can then simply use ".className" to adjust the class attribute of the selected element.

As already explained by others, id is for single use and is quicker than using class or type. So even if you have a group, if only one is ever used.. use an id.

Then you use the object/reference of 'this' from an event on an element, in this case the onclick... that will send that variable to the function / code called.

So using 'this' is a preferred option as it will always reference the element that it is used/called from.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Getelementbyid will only return one element. Probably the first one.

Comment: Yep it only does the first element in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

pass elemenet, not it's Id

```
<button class="success" id="1" onClick="reply(this)"> Added </button>
<button class="success" id="1" onClick="reply(this)"> Added </button>

function reply(elem)
{
$(elem).setAttribute('class', 'failed');

   if (elem.firstChild.data == "Added") 
   {
       elem.firstChild.data = "Add";
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep, use the js keyword 'this' to send the element itself directly... But just note, having two elements with the same id is a no no ..

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).setAttribute is not a function` error like this

Comment: Actually, the question isn't tag with jQuery, so it would be `$ is not defined`

Comment: include thi code in your <head> tag. <scrtipt src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Use a class instead of an id. ids are supposed to be unique in a dom tree.

html:

```
<button class="success" onClick="reply()"> Added </button>
<button class="success" onClick="reply()"> Added </button>
```

js:

```
 var ary_success = document.querySelectorAll(".success"); // once and forever. If the set of elements changes, move into function `reply`
 function reply () {
    var elem;
    var s_myclasses;

    for (var i=0; i < ary_success.length; i++) { 
        elem = ary_success[i];
        s_myclasses = elem.getAttribute('class');
        s_myclasses = s_myclasses.replace ( /(success|failed)/g, '' );
        s_myclasses = s_myclasses + ' failed';
        elem.setAttribute('class', s_myclasses );
        if ( elem.firstChild.data.indexOf("Added") !== -1) {
           elem.firstChild.data = "Add";
        }
    }
 }
```

Live Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/37bb3a7c/8/).

***Notes***

- Make sure that you set `ary_success`in the `onload` handler or in an appropriately placed script section - at the timeof execution the buttons must be present in the dom ! If in doubt, move it to the start of `reply`' body.
- If you employ jquery, the code simplifies (well...) to:

  $(document).ready( function () {
      $(".success").on ( 'click', function ( eve ) {
          $(".success").removeClass("success").addClass("failed");
          $(".success *:first-child:contains('Added')").text(" Add ");
      });
  });

***Updates***

- Notes,  Live Demo
- Iterator method changed, `every` not supported on test platform

Comment: Why so complex just to perform a class change?

Comment: @Mayhem Your method breaks as soon as the buttons are adormed by multiple css classes, potentially unrelated to the OP's problem, doesn't it ? Moreover, you do not set the proper classes for the siblings of the button pressed and you don't change the text.

Comment: Ahh, going by the example provided, I take it the OP would have only a level of JS knowledge.. Hence giving them a clean simple example to learn from which will resolve their issue. Their example does appear to be in the case of a simple toggle between two states. Yes multiple classes would require concat.. but using the KISS rule here

Comment: @Mayhem I see your point. However, the OP has already asked for the case in which there were several classes attached to a button (possibly without having an idea of the intricacies involved [no blame; everyone once had to learn what he knows]).

Comment: @Mayhem "if i use two class which while changing class name which one will be changed" form the OP's comment. Not sure whether I got the meaning right though.

Answer (score 1):

the ID attribute must be unique or else it will get the last defined element with that ID.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) for reference.